# Logstash configuration: how to call the partial-update API from ElasticSearch output plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to create a data pipeline where Logstash jdbc plugin get some data with SQL query every 5 minutes and ElasticSearch output plugin puts data from the input plugin into ElasticSearch server. I want this output plugin to partial-updates existing document in ElasticSearch server. my Logstash configuration file looks like:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/hello/logstash-2.3.2/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:13306/mysqlDB”
        jdbc_user => “root”
        jdbc_password => “1234”
        last_run_metadata_path => "/Users/hello/.logstash_last_run_display"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM checkout WHERE checkout_no between :sql_last_value + 1 and :sql_last_value + 5 ORDER BY checkout_no ASC"
        schedule => “*/5 * * * *"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => “checkout_no”
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }

    elasticsearch {
        action => "update"
        index => "ecs"
        document_type => “checkout”
        document_id => “%{checkout_no}"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

the problem is that ElasticSearch output plugin appears not to call partial update API such as /{index}/{type}/{id}/_update. the manual just lists actions such as `index`, `delete`, `create`, `update`, But it doesn’t mention each action calls which REST API URL, i.e) Whether `update` action calls /{index}/{type}/{id}/_update or /{index}/{type}/{id} api (upsert). I would like to call partial update api from elastic search output plugin? Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

set both `doc_as_upsert => true` and `action => "update"` works in my production script.

```
output {

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["es_host"]
    document_id => "%{id}" # !!! the id here MUST be the same
    index => "logstash-my-index"
    timeout => 30
    workers => 1
    doc_as_upsert => true
    action => "update"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. The Elasticsearch output plugin has a series of `upsert` options that correspond to the ones in Elasticsearch update API:

- `upsert` itself: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-upsert
- `scripted_upsert`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-scripted_upsert
- `doc_as_upsert`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-doc_as_upsert

Comment: This manual still confusing me. I would like to add some json keys to exsiting document in a ElasticSearch server by document id. in this case, which option do I use?

Comment: I think it should be enough to add `doc_as_upsert => true`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan it only worked for me after I also added `action => "update"` as in the accepted answer.